# What does an engine do if it has found the shortest mate?

Tags: engines, checkmate

For example, take this famous position from Kramnik vs. Deep Fritz, 2005:

```
[FEN "5N1k/6p1/7p/4P3/pp2Q3/4q3/1P4PP/2b4K w - - 0 1"]
```

Obviously White wins with Qh7#, and equally obviously, there are no possible better moves (since it's impossible to have a mate in 0).

If I let an engine run on this position, what does it do after finding the mate in 1? There's presumably nothing else to do since it has already found *the* best move. Does it just exit, then?

I tried running Stockfish 13 on this position, and it reaches depth 99/99 instantly, but I can't tell what it's doing afterwards.

Comment: I once designed an engine for connect four, and I programmed it that if it found the best possible move, it didn’t keep checking but it immediately stopped.

Comment: once stockfish reaches maximum depth it just stops the search

Comment: @Sopel This is an answer, and should be posted as such. It is also incorrect, if 100% CPU usage by Stockfish is any guide. See my comments on the existing answer.

Comment: Related: https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/21479/25131

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does what it was programmed to do.  During any Alpha-Beta pruning, the computer would stop searching and just do nothing.

In another game, like an RTS, the computer would constantly go through a todo list.
What should/can I build?
What should/can I produce?
How do I defend/attack?
...

Since a chess AI has only one objective, find the best move, there's no point in searching once it's objective if found.

Comment: This answer seems reasonable, but is easily shown to be nonsense. I copied the position into Scid, equipped with Stockfish, and started the engine. It immediately outputted 127 lines from `1 M1 1.Qh7#  (0.00)` to `127 M1 1.Qh7#  (0.00)`, but then continued to grab as many CPU cycles as it could get (sometimes its CPU usage was literally 100%, as shown in my task manager) until I stopped it. I would also like to know what Stockfish is actually doing here.

Comment: It gets worse! I tried manually playing Qh7# before running Stockfish, and it *still* hogged the CPU until I stopped it!

Comment: With M1 the score shouldn't be 0.  [jk]  Maybe the computer became sentient and is planning how to most efficiently destroy the inferior creatures of its creators.